# Checking the date before inserting in a table ORACLE 10g

Tags: oracle

I have table:

```
BOOK_DT1     BOOK_DT2   USERNAME

---------   ---------  --------------------

22-SEP-17    12-OCT-17  rSK

08-FEB-16    18-FEB-16  chak

05-JAN-17    12-JAN-17  rah

31-JAN-16    01-JUL-16  ABC
```

While inserting another column, it should check the given dates for BOOK_DT1 and BOOK_DT2 should not come into the dates present in the table.

For EX: `insert into table_name('28-SEP-17','12-NOV-17','XYX');` should throw an error, because '28-SEP-17' comes in between 22-SEP-17 and 12-OCT-17.

Comment: I'm not aware of a constraint that covers this. I believe you'll need a trigger

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this using the `after insert` trigger. Somting like this:

```
create or replace trigger date_check_trg 
after insert 
on your_table_name
 v_cnt NUMBER;
begin
  select count(*) 
  into v_cnt
  from  you_table_name t1
  join you_table_name t2
   on ( t1.BOOK_DT1 between t2.BOOK_DT1 and t2.BOOK_DT1
       or t1.BOOK_DT2 between t2.BOOK_DT1 and t2.BOOK_DT1
      )
  AND t1.rowid != t2.rowid
  ;

  if v_cnt > 0 then 
    raise_application_error(-20999, 'intersection error'); 
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried with the same way how you have given. But I am getting the below error while inserting values into table..

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20999: intersection error
ORA-06512: at "ENVMNGT.DATE_TRIGGER", line 14
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ENVMNGT.DATE_TRIGGER'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check before the insert then `BEFORE INSERT` should be what you're looking for. If the name doesn't matter and your new values should not be between any values previously inserted in the table then this is how I would write it:

```
create or replace trigger trg_date_chk
before insert 
on your_table_name for each row
declare
  lnCnt NUMBER;
begin
  select count(*) 
  into lnCnt
  from  you_table_name a
  where :new.BOOK_DT1 < a.BOOK_DT1
  and :new.BOOK_DT2 > a.BOOK_DT2;

if lnCnt > 0 then 
raise_application_error(-20999, 'INSERT ERROR HERE'); 
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Got this error DECLARE
  *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Comment: Added 'for each row' cause :new and :old works only for record triggers. Sorry about that.

Comment: Trigger created successfully . Not working correctly

Comment: Could you elaborate on why? Or how?

Comment: select * from DATES_TEST;

BOOK_DT1  BOOK_DT2  USERID
--------- --------- --------------------
22-SEP-17 12-NOV-17 rahul
20-JAN-17 10-FEB-17 ABC
21-JAN-17 20-FEB-17 xyz

It should have not allowed the insert statement given below. But it has allowed to create this row

insert into DATES_TEST values('29-SEP-17','14-NOV-17','qwe');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from DATES_TEST;

BOOK_DT1  BOOK_DT2  USERID
--------- --------- --------------------
22-SEP-17 12-NOV-17 rahul
20-JAN-17 10-FEB-17 ABC
21-JAN-17 20-FEB-17 xyz

Comment: 22-SEP-17 12-NOV-17
20-JAN-17 10-FEB-17
21-JAN-17 20-FEB-17

And you're adding 9-SEP-17 14-NOV-17. 
Of course it's gonna pass cause (9-SEP-17 14-NOV-17) is not between any of the 3 mentioned above. You should give better specifications. Cause now i have to assume also that the range you're inputting shouldn't enclose the data already in the table. If this is the case then say so

Comment: Yes Marius. The range we are inputting shouldn't enclose the data already in the table.

Comment: Then the condition should have been changed. Amended the answer
:new.BOOK_DT1 < a.BOOK_DT1
      and :new.BOOK_DT2 > a.BOOK_DT2;